# ac-auto-start (auto-complete mode) would not get set no matter what

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I'm facing a very bizarre behaviour. No matter how I set `ac-auto-start`, be it through customization, by evaluating `(setq ac-auto-start 2)`, `(setq-default ac-auto-start 2)` or `(setq-local ac-auto-start 2)` immediately after I do it, the variable is set to `nil`.

I've looked through the source of `auto-complete` mode and the `ac-slime` in my case, but none of these does nothing to this variable. I am at a loss as to how to deal with this.

The effective consequences of this malfunction is that completion combobox doesn't appear on its own, unless I force it to by doing <kbd>M-x auto-complete</kbd>. This behaviour is consistent in all modes where `auto-complete` minor mode is enabled.

**EDIT**

<s>This seems to be an issue with latest Emacs. Now it fails to modify variables values, no matter what variable it is. So, say, after running it with `-Q` I've now discovered that I can't evaluate the code that uses `(setq ...)` forms as it has no effect. :/ So, please, hold on, I'll try to investigate this...</s>

This was due to the typo, but the original problem is still there.

Emacs version is 24.3.50.1 pulled from trunk about a week ago.

---

`auto-complete` is version 1.4 installed from MELPA.

I'm setting the variable by moving the point to the REPL buffer, then <kbd>M-:</kbd>. I check its value in the same way.

**EDIT2**

OK, I finally found the reason: I had `enzyme` package installed, and it had an earlier version of `auto-complete` inside of it, for some reason parts of the `auto-complete` code were loaded from there and other parts from the one installed from MELPA. After disabling `enzyme` it all works well now.

**EDIT3**

This still happens after I run `(auto-complete-mode 1)` in the REPL buffer. The variable will become impossible to set. I've searched through various autocomplete timers that may be setting something, but no luck so far.

Comment: [The documentation](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/manual.html) suggests, albeit indirectly, that only `t` and `nil` have meaning as values for that variable. Have you tried setting it to `t`?

Comment: Maybe post some code or explanation of how you checked the value etc? What happens if you start from `emacs -Q` (the default value of `ac-auto-start` is 2 anyway, IIUC)? If you don't see the problem starting from `emacs -Q`, bisect your init file until you see what introduces the problem.

Comment: @AaronMiller: The latest stable version of autocomplete.el says that an integer value is OK too, and the default value is in fact 2. So maybe wvxvw should clarify the version used etc.

Comment: @Drew this seems to be an issue with `setq`, I'm trying to figure out what exactly went wrong.

Comment: ...this is why I wait for stable releases before upgrading; the trouble with being on the bleeding edge is that you tend to end up bleeding.

Comment: @AaronMiller I'm writing a substantial bit of Emacs Lisp code which I want to be functional in the next release... so I have to keep up with the changes :O

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed something strange going on with the setting of `auto-complete-mode`.

(I'm using the ELPA version in a GNU Emacs 24.3.1)

This is set up by `customize-group RET auto-complete` :

```
 '(ac-auto-show-menu t)
 '(ac-auto-start t)
```

At this point if you `M-x auto-complete-mode` you get a `[no match]` right in the minibuffer. Only after you try to `M-x auto-complete`, yelding a `"auto-complete-mode is not enabled"` weird error, will you be able to `M-x auto-complete-mode` (but without command completion... Hm) and then be in the mode.

If you put this in your init file (.emacs)

```
(require 'auto-complete)
(auto-complete-mode t)
```

It will be effective *only if you re-eval it* after startup (?!?).

The same with something like

```
(if (auto-complete)
    (auto-complete-mode t))
```

The *only* way that I found to **get `auto-complete-mode` to load at startup** is to :

```
(eval-and-compile
  (require 'auto-complete nil 'noerror))
```

(The above `customize` options are now effective)